# Phone mutes ringer when I dismiss alarms

Tags: audio, alarm, motorola-electrify

I have a Motorola Electrify (the Photon but on US Cellular) running Android 2.3.5. Sometimes when I dismiss my alarm in the morning, my phone mutes its ringer for some reason. I'm fairly sure it didn't used to do this, but I used Alarm Clock Extreme for a while so I'm not sure.

Why would dismissing my alarm mute my phone and how can I stop it? It's the default "Alarm and Timer" app on my phone which seems to be Motorola's customization. It's intermittent but very annoying.